# Word for numeric value that is not necessarily the result of a measuring process

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I have the phrase “mechanical properties measurement” and am looking for a good replacement for *measurement* that would not imply a measuring process, as the "measurement" in question is simply a numerical value that can also be the result of a prediction model.

Comment: Could you explain more of the context? Is this a chapter heading or is it part of a paragraph?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question.  If you want temperature you "read the thermometer".  If you want length you "measure".

Comment: Yes, please provide more context.

Comment: What *is* a "mechanical properties measurement"? What properties? What are you (not) measuring? The answer may and probably will greatly depend on that. Is it density, frequency, elasticity, inertia, angle of attack, plasticity, something else entirely, some of them, all of them, none of them? It is not clear at all what you are asking. If you can't find a good word with all the context that you do have, how are we expected to find it without any context whatsoever? Also, what alternatives exactly have you considered and rejected so far? We need to know that so as not to repost them.

Comment: I would suggest (but the question is closed) "parameter"

Comment: The asker sounds like an engineer.  The word that he is looking for is value.  Result, Assay (or assayance), reading, intensity, magnitude, and indication might also work.

Answer (score 4):

**[evaluate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/evaluate)** (noun form: **evaluation**)

> Form an idea of the amount, number, or value of; assess:
>
> *Mathematics* Find a numerical expression or equivalent for (an equation, formula, or function)
>
> (Oxford)

If you evaluate something, you get a result; which is not necessarily measured.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest ***[quantify](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantify),*** as defined by Merriam Webster:

> to find or calculate the quantity or amount of (something)
>   to determine, express, or measure the quantity of

Comment: How easy.Quantification is good word for me. In my context, it will be something like chapter heading. My first idea was to use determination, but quantification is better.

Comment: I also considered about evaluation which is derived from value, but this word is more frequently used without necessity to obtain numerical result. Definition of evaluation is: The making of a judgement about the amount, number, or value of something; assessment. Quatation in Oxford is ‘the evaluation of each method’. But evaluation of method don't require numerical results